# why heroku app doesn't store the data in the database?

Tags: heroku

I've built an internal app that is used only for the organization. The app works fine - it has a form which users fill in and save. It works for few hours that the form is stored in the database, but after a few hours the database is seemingly purged and the app shows no data - as if it's been started for the first time. I checked the log, but couldn't find anything. What and where can I check to find out what's going on? Could it be the case that since I'm using free heroku, it restarts after 24 hours.

Comment: see https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Comment: What database are you using? If it's something like SQLite, that's not gonna work.

Comment: Yeah, it was SQLite3 that I was using. As @TinNguyen provided in the link, it drops the files. So, I'll be working on setting up a database addon. Thanks for the information. This was very helpful